# How to parse or generate dynamic SQL from react querybuilder output json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js, query-builder, jquery-query-builder

for one of my project we are using react-querybuilder lib and the end result will be sent to server to filter data accordingly, my backend use Sequelize, Express with JavaScript.

My concern is how to make sql queries or   Sequelize command from the output json of react querybuilder

The output json is something like below-

```
{
  "combinator": "and",
  "rules": [
    {
      "field": "first_name",
      "operator": "beginsWith",
      "value": "Stev",
    },
    {
      "field": "last_name",
      "operator": "in",
      "value": "Vai, Vaughan",
    },
  ],
}
```

I could use the formatQuery to make sql from it but will that raise any security concerns or is there nay other proper approach to implement this on backend?

Answer (score 1):

`formatQuery` can produce SQL `WHERE` clauses with inline values, but also with parameterized values that can be used as bind variables by a database client. The parameterized format can greatly reduce (but ***not*** eliminate!) the risk of SQL injection attacks.

If you were running straight SQL, I would recommend using the [`parameterized`](https://react-querybuilder.js.org/docs/utils/export#parameterized-sql) or [`parameterized_named`](https://react-querybuilder.js.org/docs/utils/export#named-parameters) formats, but with Sequelize I don't know if `formatQuery` will actually help. You might need to create your own transformer to convert from RQB to Sequelize.

Also (I hope this is appropriate here), I created a training course for `react-querybuilder` that covers both server- and client-based SQL generation. It's called [Building Advanced Admin Reporting in React](https://www.newline.co/courses/building-advanced-admin-reporting-in-react).